# npm install doesn't work empty node_modules

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I have an old project, where there is a package.json, where there are Dependencies and DevDependecies and also cordovaPlugins defined (Ionic Project). When I use npm install I get no error just warnings, that there is no description, no repository field and invalid name.

This ist the output of npm install -ddd:

`npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\MAG\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   '-ddd',
npm verb cli   'install' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.9
npm info using node@v4.6.1
npm sill loadCurrentTree Starting
npm sill install loadCurrentTree
npm sill install readLocalPackageData
npm sill install normalizeTree
npm sill loadCurrentTree Finishing
npm sill loadIdealTree Starting
npm sill install loadIdealTree
npm sill cloneCurrentTree Starting
npm sill install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
npm sill cloneCurrentTree Finishing
npm sill loadShrinkwrap Starting
npm sill install loadShrinkwrap
npm sill loadShrinkwrap Finishing
npm sill loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
npm sill install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
npm sill loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Finishing
npm sill loadIdealTree Finishing
npm sill currentTree ionic
npm sill idealTree ionic
npm sill generateActionsToTake Starting
npm sill install generateActionsToTake
npm sill generateActionsToTake Finishing
npm sill diffTrees action count 0
npm sill decomposeActions action count 0
npm sill runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
npm sill install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
npm sill preinstall ionic C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\ionic-82edf1f0
npm info lifecycle undefined~preinstall: undefined
npm sill lifecycle undefined~preinstall: no script for preinstall, continuing
npm sill executeActions Starting
npm sill install executeActions
npm sill doSerial global-install 0
npm sill doParallel fetch 0
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\MAG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\MAG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-2e8b4ab8cc917933.lock for C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\node_modules\.staging
npm sill doParallel extract 0
npm sill doParallel preinstall 0
npm sill doReverseSerial remove 0
npm sill doSerial move 0
npm sill doSerial finalize 0
npm sill doSerial build 0
npm sill doSerial global-link 0
npm sill doParallel update-linked 0
npm sill doSerial install 0
npm sill doSerial postinstall 0
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\MAG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-2e8b4ab8cc917933.lock for C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\node_modules\.staging
npm sill executeActions Finishing
npm sill rollbackFailedOptional Starting
npm sill rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
npm sill install runPostinstallTopLevelLifecycles
npm sill build ionic
npm info linkStuff !invalid#1
npm sill linkStuff !invalid#1 has C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app as its parent node_modules
npm verb linkBins !invalid#1
npm verb linkMans !invalid#1
npm sill install ionic C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\ionic-82edf1f0
npm info lifecycle undefined~install: undefined
npm sill lifecycle undefined~install: no script for install, continuing
npm sill postinstall ionic C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\ionic-82edf1f0
npm info lifecycle undefined~postinstall: undefined
npm sill lifecycle undefined~postinstall: no script for postinstall, continuing
npm sill prepublish ionic C:\Users\MAG\Documents\app\trunk\amp-app\ionic\ionic-82edf1f0
npm info lifecycle undefined~prepublish: undefined
npm sill lifecycle undefined~prepublish: no script for prepublish, continuing
npm sill runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
npm sill install printInstalled
npm WARN Invalid name: "active mobile"
npm verb
npm verb If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm verb     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN ionic No description
npm verb
npm verb If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm verb     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN ionic No repository field.
npm verb
npm verb If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm verb     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN ionic No README data
npm verb
npm verb If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm verb     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN ionic No license field.
npm verb
npm verb If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm verb     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok`

I get a node_modules folder but it's empty. Can it be the node-version? Using 4.* . And if yes how can I find out, which Node or NPM version I should use?

Comment: Post the package.json file too (edit it into the question please). The version of node is okay, it shouldn't impact how NPM works.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the file package.json, please include then for have a better response.

I have some ideas.

1) the log say :

`npm WARN Invalid name: "active mobile"`

are you check if that exist in your package.json?

2) you can try to clean the npm cache

```
npm cache clean
```

upgrade the npm version, exist many ways to made depends your system, more info in the  [npm Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)

3) you can update the general version of cordova and ionic in your machine. Some time ago I have a similar problem, and the solution was update cordova.

```
npm update -g cordova ionic
```

4) you can install nvm, it's a easy way to change the node version, and check if one of your modules need a specific version of node.

[nvm repository](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted ... my issue was with having space in the name, and even though it would show a "WARNING" there was zero other output as to why nothing would install ... drove me insane for an hour or two